# Laravel withtrashed in a relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Order model and a Service model.

An order can be deleted (soft delete).
I want to list all orders, deleted and active and the service that it belongs to.

**Order Model**:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function service ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Service');
    }
}
```

**Service Model**:

```
class Service extends Model
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Order');
    }
}
```

What I tried:

```
$company=Company::with('orders.service'=>function ($query) {
        $query->withTrashed();
    },'services'])->where('id',$company->id)->get();
```

But this returns no orders (and right now I only have 1 deleted order in my db)

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use

```
 public function order() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('Order')->withTrashed();
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but that will return all the deleted orders too, all the time. What if i dont need the deleted orders on a page?

Comment: another hacky solution I'm not proud of is to define 2 relations, one with trashed and the other without.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a `belongsToMany` relationship always goes with another `belongsToMany` relationship at the other side, so you are not doing right the relationships.

If you want a many to many relationship, both models should have a `belongsToMany` relationship to the other model, and you must have a pivot table.

If you want a one to many relationship, one model should have a `belongsTo` relationship and the other a `hasMany` relationship.

Comment: @user3844579 Please, can you confirm which is the relationship that you want?

Comment: @user3844579 Please, update the code of your question with the canges. Also, explain the code you have tried and what you are trying to achieve.