# hasMany Relationship has not withTrashed()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I seen this answer to a similar question here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40654005/1055279

Here I see

```
public function order() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('Order')->withTrashed();
 }
```

In my scenario I've `Customer` models that have *n* `Device`s

```
// Relation 1 to n from Customer model to Device model
public function devices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Device')->withTrashed();
}
```

Note I've added withTrashed, because I've ALWAYS the need to retrieve softDeleted data.

### The problem

Retriving devices from a customer model I got

> message: "Call to undefined method 
>     Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::withTrashed()"

Probably I'm using wrong syntax. I'm here to ask a kindly help.

- Laravel is @5.8.19
- PHP is @7.2.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended that the target model *was not* using SoftDelete trait.

Fixed.